# what model classes should represent?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class, stored-procedures, model

I'm rather new to software development and I am very confused as what classes in the model should represent, i will elaborate a scenario and i will ask a couple questions at the end. I'm using VS 2013 with MVC.

I have 3 tables, 
tblStudent (*StudentID, StudentName, StudentLastName, StudentDateOfBirth)
tblModule (*ModuleID, ModuleName, ModuleDescription)
tblStudentModules (*StudentID, *ModuleID) - table created to break many to many relationships

And i want to execute this query using a stored procedure in the database:

```
SELECT A.StudentID
  ,A.StudentName]
  ,A.StudentLastName
  ,B.ModuleName
FROM tblStudent A, tblModule B, tblStudentModules C
Where A.StudentID = C.StudentID
      And B.ModuleID = C.ModuleID
```

Now, my query uses 3 tables, and the result is a combination of different attributes of the tables i have, so should my model classes represent individual objects (i.e Student, modules ) or should they represent the result set of the Query that i want to execute (a class with StudentID, StudentName       ,StudentLastName, ModuleName) so I can map the result of the stored procedure to a single model class?

Comment: Typically you will have data model that map to your database tables (no doubt you will need these to be able to create and edit `Student` and `Module` objects), and view models that combine data from different data models (so if your not using EF, then you can map your SP to the view model)

Comment: View Model, that's the thing i was looking for, thank you for pointing me in the right direction! ... do you know how can i Map the SP to the view model? i cannot find much documentation on using stored procedures nowadays, are they obsolete now?

Comment: Certainly not obsolete, but less common with many people using EF. Create a method in a service that returns your view model, and opena connection, execute a DataReader and read the values into your view model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Models are the business layer when considering MVC applications. It will be created based on database structure. Always create models for the tables of your database. 
**That is, you should need to create models for  *tblStudent ,  tblModule and  tblStudentModules .***

ViewModel is one of the unspoken layer in the Asp.Net MVC application. It fits between Model and View and act as a data container for View. ViewModel is View specific data. It will be created based on the View. So, you need to create viewmodels based on every view. These viewmodels may or may not contain variables of the original models.

**That is, you need to create a viewmodel for the stored procedure you are writing which contains *StudentID, StudentName, StudentLastName and ModuleName.* That is, what all things we need to display in a view page are the variables of the viewmodel.**

- View is going to be a strongly typed view of type ViewModel.
- Model and ViewModel should be independent of each other. Controller
  will create and initialises ViewModel object based on one or more
  Model object.

Comment: Tank you very much! this is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Personal opinion - but a class in a model as described above should represent a 'thing', be it a Student, a Module, or a Relationship between the two.

If you were to use Entity Framework for example to interact with the database from code then this is how the database would be represented, a collection of three classes, one for each of the tables you have described.

Comment: actually EF would normal ignore the linking table and convert it into collections of objects on each of the other 2, unless of course the link contained additional data

Comment: if I get this straight, is it possible to use EF to create the model, and then have my own 'View Models'?, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complex subject that can't have a quick answer however the cut down version is:

Don't confuse the database model with the object model, while there are many point of similarity they are not the same thing.

An Object is a Entity that contains naturally grouped items and functions

Where as a Table is normalised representation of data

To use your example you have Students and Modules that are primary entities that uses a 3rd table to maintain a relationship

On the object model you would have a Student class, and a Module class
the Student class would have a collection of modules inside it. so the student will manage its own relationships with modules and each module may contain a collection of student allowing it to maintain its relationship as well.

However a Student is a Type of Person so you might define a Person class and then have student Inherit from this class and expand its functionality to include student behaviour, now in this situation a person would probably not have any meaning unless filter through a child class such as student or teacher.
in the database this is hard to maintain as you can't have a person table that doesn't exist

This is where the idea of MVC and MVVM comes in as this encourages you to create a layered system so you have your bottom layer that manages the database object relationship and your top layer that handles your User object interaction

Comment: Very useful explanation, I think I had been mixing up the tow concepts so i was indeed very confused, thank you!